# laravel 8, how to get individual errors message in array based on the field names instead of this default array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a contact form, with some field and i want to get error message based on the form field, i.e the error message for name, email, phone, subject and message

Here is what I get here:

```
    XHRPOSThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/save
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 137ms]

    success false
    errors  [ "The name field is required.", "The email field is required.", "The phone field is required.", "The subject field is required.", "The description field is required." ]
```

because of this line in controller

```
$validator->errors()->all()
```

but I want the error message to be like:

```
errors:object{name:""The name field is required." 
  email:"The email field is required.", ...}
```

the controllers look like

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:60',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required|min:10|numeric',
        'subject' => 'required|max:100',
        'description' => 'required|max:250',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
           'success' => false, 'errors' =>$validator->errors()->all()
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: try this if($validator->fails()){ return response(['errors' => $validator->errors()]); }

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the default Laravel validation function (available in all controllers), which handles this output automatically:

```php
// SomeController.php
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => 'required|max:60',
   // ...
]);
```

When the validation fails, a `ValidationException` is thrown which should be automatically handled in your exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with using FormRequest for validation and custom messages.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$exampleRequest = new ExampleRequest();
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $exampleRequest->rules(), $exampleRequest->messages());

if($validator->fails()){
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
}
```

This will return JSON response (for an API in this case):

```
{
    "name": [
        "First name is required."
    ]
}
```

For given rules and messages in ExampleRequest:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // 'name' => 'required',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.required' => 'First name is required.'
    ];
}
```